# Is it possible to end a while loop with a try/except statement?

Tags: python, terminate, try-except

So the goal here is to end my `while loop`, or my script really if a user's bank amount reaches `0 (zero)` or if the user inputs a `0 (zero)` for bet amount to terminate the script. THE PROBLEM is that I am NOT allowed to use a `break` statement, and though the program works perfectly with `exit()`, I cannot use that either because we haven't "gotten there yet" via the book (the instructor wants us to use what we are learning in the book and not what we already know).
I am just really stumped. Part of it is because I struggle a lot with the try/except statements so maybe I am just doing something wrong there, or maybe I need to try a different loop. Maybe you guys can help?
Gonna post my code below. As far as I am concerned, everything works perfectly fine, but I cannot use `exit()` or `break` so I need some advice on another python basics-orientated method...
So can I use try/except? If so, how?
I need the program to continue looping unless banking reaches `0 (zero)` or user input is equal to `0 (zero)`, it's why I chose the `while loop`. Do I need to use a different loop method?
The help will be GREATLY appreciated and I thank everyone in advance.

```
import random

def rollDice(cnt):
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    x = int(die1 + die2)
    print('Roll #', cnt, 'was', x)
    return x

def total_bank(bank):
    bet = 0
    while bet <= 0 or bet > min([500,bank]):
        print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
        get_bet = input('Enter your bet (or 0 to quit): ')
        if get_bet == '0': 
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            exit()
        bet = int(get_bet)
    return bank,bet

def get_guess():
    guess = 0
    while (guess < 2 or guess > 12):
        try:
            guess = int(input('Choose a number between 2 and 12: '))
        except ValueError:
            guess = 0
        return guess

bank = 500
guess = get_guess
rcnt = 1

while rcnt < 4:
    rcnt = 0
    bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess == rollDice(rcnt+1):
        bank += bet * 2
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+2):
        bank += bet * .5
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+3):
        bank = bank
    else:
        bank = bank - bet
        if bank == 0:
            print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            exit()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly exit the loop using an exception; just raise an exception inside your `while` loop, and catch it outside the loop:

```
def total_bank(bank):
    bet = 0
    try:
        while bet <= 0 or bet > min([500,bank]):
            print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
            get_bet = input('Enter your bet (or 0 to quit): ')
            if get_bet == '0': 
                print('Thanks for playing!')
                raise StopIteration()
            bet = int(get_bet)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return bank,bet
```

But even easier is just to return from inside the loop:

```
def total_bank(bank):
    bet = 0
    while bet <= 0 or bet > min([500,bank]):
        print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
        get_bet = input('Enter your bet (or 0 to quit): ')
        bet = int(get_bet)
        if get_bet == '0': 
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            return bank, bet
        return bank, bet
```

Comment: Another option would be create a variable stop=False and add a condition to the while like `while bet <= 0 or bet > min([500,bank]) or stop == False´ and you can change stop to true inside the if

Comment: The only problem with the second solution it now raises a NoneType error for my bank, bet = total_bank(bank) statement in the while loop.

Comment: I think it is because you need bet=0 before the while statement otherwise bet will not be defined but I'm not sure

Comment: @FlavioMoraes yeah, I just tried that doing that but it did not work either. I am not sure what I should do. Tbh exit() would have solved my problems, but unfortunately, I am not allowed to include any of my current knowledge. I will just have to keep playing around with it till I figure out. Perhaps others may have some advice. Regardless, if it weren't for the error, I think this solution would have been a perfect, simple fix.

Comment: have you tried my suggestion of adding a condition to the if?

Comment: There was a line that went missing between your question and this answer. Try the second solution now.

Comment: @larsks Just gave it a shot, and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: We were also missing a `return` statement (for when the `while` loop exits due to the condition).

Comment: @larsks that was a pretty great fix, though it still loops the "Choose a number between 2 and 12" after printing the termination message.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not super knowledgable with the try and except functions but with the try block you could raise an error and end the program like that.